# Enable SSL on GitLab with Docker on Synology NAS

Tags: ssl, docker, gitlab, synology

I have a working installation of GitLab via the official GitLab Package on my Synology NAS (DSM 5.2) in a Docker container.

I now like to access the Webinterface via https instead of just http. I have seen in several posts that it is possible to do with some docker magic, but
did not find any detailed instructions.

Can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

It's a pity that this is not default.

Comment: Official docs: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated which gitlab image you're using:

- https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=gitlab

The most common container image already has instructions included with details on how to enable SSL:

- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sameersbn/gitlab/

Comment: I use the Synology Package for GitLab which lives in a Docker Conatiner. In the Docker control panel it says the image is sameersbn/gitlab:7.9.3

Comment: I will have a look at that instructions. Looks doable on the first sight.

Answer (score 13):

With DSM6, the changes (except generation of the cert) are now possible using the dsm docker interface:

1) Create a key/cert:

```
mkdir /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
cd /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
openssl genrsa -out gitlab.key 2048
openssl req -new -key gitlab.key -out gitlab.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in gitlab.csr -signkey gitlab.key -out gitlab.crt
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
chmod 400 gitlab.key
```

2) Set up gitlab docker environment:

[image: setting gitlab docker environment vars via DSM gui]

3) Set gitlab docker port bindings:
[image: Set port binding for gitlab]

Comment: this has to be repeated if a package update has been installed :/

Comment: Nowadays you should generate the `certs` folder at: `/volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs` (notice the double `/gitlab/`)

Comment: I confirm this solution is the most efficient. Nevertheless, as mentionned @Jouke, the `certs/` directory should be into `/volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/`. Also : The gitlab service must be off to be edited, and be restarted only when everything is ready.

Answer (score 6):

On DSM 6.2.1

I just did the installation of this and some of the answers here helped me but i still ran into problems. So i thought to share my findings:

> I wanted to use the lets-encrypt certs i already had generated inside Synology DSM.

1. Create a task scheduler (user defined script)

   ```
   cp /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/privkey.pem  /volume1/docker/gitlab-ce/gitlab/certs/gitlab.key
   cp /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/fullchain.pem /volume1/docker/gitlab-ce/gitlab/certs/gitlab.crt
   ```

   > adjust to your chosen name/folder when installing gitlab (in my case "gitlab-ce")
2. Create a dhparam.pem file on any machine with open ssl

   ```
   openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
   ```

   > I advice not to do this on a NAS, because it will be slow (you may increase key complexity to which ever you have patients for waiting)
3. Copy the dhparam.pm to your certificats folder location inside gitlab

   ```
   /volume1/docker/gitlab-ce/gitlab/certs/
   ```

   > adjust to your chosen name/folder when installing gitlab (in my case "gitlab-ce")
4. Stop gitlab in package center (stops all tree docker containers)
5. On the synology_gitlab container

   5.1 Add the two environment variables

   ```
   GITLAB_HTTPS=true  
   SSL_SELF_SIGNED=false
   ```

   5.2. Change gitlab port binding (container port) from 80 to 443

This approach will automatically at a set time (your choice in the user defined script) update you generated ssl certificate if the Synology DSM (or you manually) creates a new one. This is however not an instant update, but you can trigger it manually from the task scheduler interface. Still this approach is kind of care free for personal NAS solutions.

Comment: footnote: be aware that gitlab is only picking up the new certificate when you restart gitlab from the package manager.

Answer (score 4):

The instructions Crami gave work for me with the package install (sameersbn/gitlab:7.9.3).  You must:

1. Follow the command line instructions from Crami to generate the certificate:

   ```
   mkdir /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
   cd /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
   openssl genrsa -out gitlab.key 2048
   openssl req -new -key gitlab.key -out gitlab.csr
   openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in gitlab.csr -signkey gitlab.key -out gitlab.crt
   openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
   chmod 400 gitlab.key
   ```
2. Stop the package in the Package Center
3. Edit the configuration file at
   `/usr/syno/etc/packages/Docker/synology_gitlab.config`.  It's a JSON file rather than command line, but is easy to see what to change/add.  You need to add:

   ```
   {
      "key" : "GITLAB_HTTPS",
      "value" : "true"
   },
   {
      "key" : "SSL_SELF_SIGNED",
      "value" : "true"
   },
   ```

   as well as the port binding from 80 instead to 443 in the same file:

   ```
   {
      "container_port" : 443,
      "host_port" : 30000,
      "type" : "tcp"
   },
   ```
4. Start the package in Package Center

Comment: Something I've noticed about this method (editing the config) is that it gets blown away every time I restart the package in the Package Center (i.e., restart the container, really).  Looking over in ../Docker-GitLab/config, I see environment variables, however changing those seems to do nothing at all when re-starting the image.

Answer (score 2):

I used @helt solution but looking at the docker info page (https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab/#ssl), I seen that the certs folder is at "docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs/"...

For the @helt solution, I updated this:

```
mkdir /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs
cd /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs
openssl genrsa -out gitlab.key 2048
openssl req -new -key gitlab.key -out gitlab.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in gitlab.csr -signkey gitlab.key -out gitlab.crt
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
chmod 400 gitlab.key
```

When I used only "/volume1/docker/gitlab/certs", when accessing the GitLab page, I had an error page with "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR", after using "/volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs", error disappeared and everything works fine...

My Synology station is a DS718+ running DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 3.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a new docker container on the NAS with all working like i want it.

you have to create the ssl certificates like in the description of the gitlab package like this:

```
mkdir /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
cd /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
openssl genrsa -out gitlab.key 2048
openssl req -new -key gitlab.key -out gitlab.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in gitlab.csr -signkey gitlab.key -out gitlab.crt
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
chmod 400 gitlab.key
```

and then remove and recreate the container:

```
docker rm synology_gitlab    

docker run --name synology_gitlab -d --link synology_gitlab_redis:redisio \
  --publish 30001:22 --publish 30080:80 --publish 30000:443 \
  --env "GITLAB_HTTPS=true" --env "SSL_SELF_SIGNED=true" \
  --env "GITLAB_HOST=nas.freestone.net" \
  --env "GITLAB_PORT=30000" \
  --env "GITLAB_SSH_PORT=30001" \
  --env "GITLAB_EMAIL=your@example.com" \
  --env "DB_TYPE=mysql" \
  --env "DB_HOST=172.17.42.1" \
  --env "DB_NAME=gitlab" \
  --env "DB_USER=gitlab" \
  --env "DB_PASS=yourdbpassword" \
  --env "SMTP_ENABLED=true" \
  --env "SMTP_DOMAIN=mailserver.example.com" \
  --env "SMTP_HOST=mailserver.example.com" \
  --env "SMTP_PORT=587" \
  --env "SMTP_USER=user@example.com" \
  --env "SMTP_PASS=mailpassword" \
  --env "SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE=none" \
  --volume /volume1/docker/gitlab/:/home/git/data \
  sameersbn/gitlab:7.9.3
```

Then you should be up and running again. Port 30000 is now https and no longer http.

Comment: You may also use the latest version of gitlab and redis, as long as you have installed the Syno package first and then stopped it. Synology does something to open up MariaDB to Docker, which is something I cannot figure out how to do on my own...

Comment: doesn't work for me. the docker container shut down after ~1 minute. and it doesn't even consume any ram. the original container uses about 1GB. and I cannot connect to gitlab anymore after it.